# Error en la consola de NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, consola

Cuando ingreso las instrucciones en la consola manda el siguiente mensaje:
npm should be run outside of the Node.js REPL, in your normal shell.

me gustaría saber si fue un error de instalación o que es lo que pasa.

Comment: la instruccion que ingreso es: npm init

Comment: Seguramente has escrito `node` en tu terminal y al presionar `enter` se abre el `REPL` (el entorno de `node`) y estás tratando de ejecutar `npm init` allí. Esa no es la forma correcta. `npm init` debes ejecutarlo directamente desde el `shell` (consola) del sistema operativo (sin entrar a `node`). Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Creo que usted ha ingresado primero el comando `node` sin ningún argumento. Esto lo ingresa a usted al modo REPL de NodeJS. Node REPL no esta diseñado para ejecutar comandos `npm`. El modo REPL se ve como lo siguiente:

[image: Cómo se ve el modo REPL de Node]

Pero no se preocupe ya que la instalación de Node parece estar correcta. Lo que queda por hacer es salir del modo REPL de Node. Para salir del modo REPL, debe ingresar `.exit` y presionar Enter o simplemente presionar <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> dos veces seguidas según la documentación official en inglés que se encuentra aquí: https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-use-the-nodejs-repl#dot-commands. A mí me funcionó presionando <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> una sola vez en mi mac.

Una vez que haya salido del modo REPL de Node, usted deberá estar de vuelta en el prompt de su sistema operativo, en donde podrá ingresar `npm init` y la computadora lo entenderá.